# HorizontalPager overlaps DotIndicator

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I try to make a simple carousel images slider.
My code for my slider:

```
    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun CarouselSlider(images: List<Int>) {
    val state = rememberPagerState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        HorizontalPager(
            state = state,
            pageCount = images.size,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(300.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) { page ->
            Box() {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(images[page]),
                    contentDescription = "",
                    Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                )
            }
        }
        DotsIndicator(
            pageCount = images.size,
            selectedIndex = state.currentPage
        )
    }
}
```

Here a pager and an indicator are in one column.
The indicator is from the official docs:

```
@Composable
fun DotsIndicator(
pageCount: Int,
selectedIndex: Int
) {
Box() {
    Row(
        Modifier
            .height(50.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        repeat(pageCount) { iteration ->
            val color = if (selectedIndex == iteration) Color.DarkGray else Color.LightGray
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(2.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
                    .background(color)
                    .size(20.dp)

            )
        }
    }
}
}
```

The Pager works, but I didn't see the Indicator. Maybe it had overlapped by the Pager. Where is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!
The code above is OK. But in the other file I have an outer container:

```
  Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(300.dp)
```

etc so that the pager had 300.dp height and the outer box had the same height. And we had no space for dots indicator! Extra height solved the problem.

```
  Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(320.dp)
```